# Is it possible to build all features of functional language with only closure?

Tags: languages, functional-programming, interpreters

I'm trying to make a new functional language and it's interpreter for practice.
As I know most basic building block is only a lambda function, and it's just a closure.
I'm not understanding them well, so I want to ask about I'm right or what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at SIOD (Scheme in one Defun) and some of the more stripped down versions of scheme and lisp. It is amazing just how small scheme really is. 
You need a function construction and about 5 special forms and you have a lisp interpreter.
(It won't be a fast one but it will work)

And of course take a look at SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) You can find it online at the mitpress website.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an absolutely minimal set of primitives, use [SK calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_calculus), see the [Unlambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlambda) language.

Otherwise, a simple term-rewriting engine implementing a basic [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) will be sufficient.

*Update*: forgot to mention - both ways will not introduce closure as an atomic primitive.

Answer (score 1):

In the purest [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#The_lambda_calculus), the only thing that is required to perform any computation is the lambda function. Alonzo Church described one possible encoding of numbers, with which the mere application of a specially-formed lambda performs work.

Even in Lisp, the entirety of the language can be constructed from lambdas. The workhorse is the [Y combinator](http://ece.olin.edu/focs/current/lecture_notes/05_Y/Y.pdf) (PDF warning). With it, you can implement anonymous recursive functions; within the scope of which you can construct all of the forms needed to implement the most basic Lisp dialect.

Honestly, it's all quite a bit over my head, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it, so I hope I haven't horribly butchered this. :)

Comment: Y-combinator does not need to be an atomic primitive.

Comment: @SK-logic: I never said it did. The only atomic primitive I'm talking about is the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, closure is not absolutely necessary. Closures are convenient because they "fix" a lexical environment. A closure sent as an argument includes its bound variables so they don't need to be sent as well. Any task that can be accomplished with a closure can be accomplished without one by explicitly sending both the function and variables as arguments. Think of the power of combinators.

Lambdas and closure make a language easier to use or more expressive. Just don't forget first class functions in your new language.